# Python script not running with Windows task scheduler due to numpy

Tags: python, windows, numpy, windows-task-scheduler

Running a basic python script with the windows task scheduler only works when I comment out the import statement for numpy and I can't figure out why.

Details:

I was previously trying to run a more complex script but in order to narrow down the issues I was having I ended up creating the following basic script to test run with the task scheduler.

```
import numpy

outDIR = "C:\\Users\\trill_gates\\OneDrive\\Documents\\DS Projects\\"

f = open(outDIR + "demofile2.txt", "w")
f.write("Test Text")
f.close()
```

Running the script normally does not produce any issues. However, when I set it up to run with task scheduler, the file its supposed to write to isn't created. Only when the `import numpy` statement is commented out does it work again. In the proper script I need run on a schedule, I'm using numpy and that seems to also be what was causing the script to not run. I tried this on two separate computers, uninstalled and reinstalled anaconda as well as created a clean conda environment with just the necessary packages and I'm still getting the same error.

This is the setup I'm using in task scheduler to call the script.

[image]

I'm using an anaconda distribution of python 3.7.7 and numpy 1.18.5.

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar.   Updated to Python 3.7 yesterday and it seems to have killed the ability to execute scheduled tasks.  The error I get is numpy related even though the script doesn't use numpy. . More shortly.